# Как реализовать продолжение после регистрации на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть форма регистрации написанная на html и css. Как открыть главную страницу после прохождения регистрации и нажатие на кнопку Submit, я новечек в js html css, поэтому не совсем допераю, надо прописывать главную страницу в другом файле html? Если да то как на неё потом перейти? Или же прописывать главную страницу в этом же html документе?

Comment: `location = 'нужная Вам страница';`

Comment: сначала розберитесь куда идут вашы дание

Comment: редирект на сервере

Answer (score 1):

Он вряд ли сервером то пользуется
Напиши в js файле location = 'главная_страница(название файла твое).html';